# Multiple orWhere() in whereHas() in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder, wherehas

**Contact Model**

```
class Contact extends Model
{
    public function Account()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('app\Account');
    }
}
```

**Account Model**

```
class Account extends Model
{
    public function Contact()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('app\Contact');
    }
}
```

I want to get query of all Contacts that have `account_name = 'test'` or `account_city ='test2'`.

```
$query = Contact::query();
    $query->whereHas('Account', function ($q) {
        $q->orwhere('account_name' ,'=', 'test');
        $q->orwhere('account_city','=','test2');
    });
$query->get;
```

This query shows me all Contacts that have an `Account` but I want to get only Contacts that have `account_name = 'test'` or `account_city ='test2'`

**Result of `$query->tosql();`**

```
select * from `contacts` where exists (select * from `accounts` where (`contacts`.`account_id` = `accounts`.`id` or (`account_name` = ? or `account_city` = ?)) and `accounts`.`deleted_at` is null) and `contacts`.`deleted_at` is null
```

Comment: could you help to do [`$query->toSql()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_toSql) to see the actual generated sql query?

Comment: I edit my post ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$query=Contact::query();
$query->whereHas('Account', function ($q) {
    $q->where(function($query) {
       $query->where('account_city','test2')->orWhere('account_name','test');
    });
});
$query->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 $query=Contact::query();
 $query  =  $query->whereHas('Account', function ($q)  {
       $q->orwhere('account_name',test');
       $q->orwhere('account_city','test2');
 });
 $query->get;
```

I think it will do the trick.

Comment: I know this but I create dynamic query and maybe I have `like` or '>' ,....

Comment: these can also be done.Go through Laravel Docs .These are very helpful